# how to pass logon informations to the standalone crystal Report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, windows

I am using Standalone crystal report in my project which is in windows application. Here i want to pass the logon credentials. the following code am using.

```
Private Sub cmd_print_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmd_print.Click
        Dim strConnection As String = "..."
        Dim cr As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        Dim strReportPath As String = "d:\ReportFtLabel.rpt"
        cr.Load(strReportPath)

        Dim ConnectInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo
        With ConnectInfo
            .ServerName = "RRRR"
            .DatabaseName = "RRRR"
            .UserID = "XXXX"
            .Password = "XXXX"
        End With

        For Each Table As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In cr.Database.Tables
            Dim LogOnInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo

            LogOnInfo = Table.LogOnInfo
            LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConnectInfo
            Table.ApplyLogOnInfo(LogOnInfo)
        Next

        objSCIP_ml = New SCIP_ml
        objSCIP_bll = New scip_bll
        Dim DS As New DataSet
        DS = objSCIP_bll.bll_GetHandShake(objSCIP_ml)
        If Not DS Is Nothing Then
            cr.Load(strReportPath)
            cr.SetDataSource(DS)
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr
            CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
        End If
        DS = Nothing
        objSCIP_ml = Nothing
        objSCIP_bll = Nothing
    End Sub
```

But it throws the following error.

[image: error]

somewhere i am missing to pass the logon information... 
Any suggestions and solutions is very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can add it to your App config as keys like:

```
    <add key="ServerName" value="RRRR"/>
    <add key="DataBaseName" value="RRRR"/>
    <add key="DatabaseUser" value="XXXX"/>
    <add key="DatabasePassword" value="XXXX"/>
```

and call them in your code like:

```
    Dim SERVER_NAME As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ServerName").ToString()
    Dim DATABASE_NAME As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DataBaseName").ToString()
    Dim DatabaseUser As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DatabaseUser").ToString()
    Dim DatabasePassword As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DatabasePassword").ToString()
    .UserID = "XXXX"
    .Password = "XXXX"
```

Comment: Config file is available in plain text. Your approach will expose the password to everybody

Comment: you can encrypt the password and decrypt it in the code.... it`s not a big deal. i can provide an encryption code.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing the connection information and the datasource. You need to do one or the other.

**Remove** this code

```
        Dim ConnectInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo
    With ConnectInfo
        .ServerName = "RRRR"
        .DatabaseName = "RRRR"
        .UserID = "XXXX"
        .Password = "XXXX"
    End With

    For Each Table As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In cr.Database.Tables
        Dim LogOnInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo

        LogOnInfo = Table.LogOnInfo
        LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConnectInfo
        Table.ApplyLogOnInfo(LogOnInfo)
    Next
```

Check this link how to set datasource:
http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2006/09/Feeding-Crystal-Reports-from-your-application.aspx